# Clearcase, How to disallow checkin when comment is not provided

Tags: triggers, clearcase, checkin

I've spent hours and looked for a solution on internet to figure out how to disallow a checkin operation when comment is not provided by the developer.

I am trying to write a preop checkin trigger which is triggered before every checkin that checks if comment field is empty or not.

So far I've managed only display message to the user, but I couldn't find a way to interrupt checkin operation.

Thanks in advance, any help would be appreciated.

edit: the command for installing trigger as follows:

`mktrtype -element -all -preop checkin -exec <trigger_path> COMMENT_CONTROL`

Comment: What language are you using for your trigger? Perl? VBScript? Something else?

Comment: I really recommend calling a script instead of calling directly a command. That way, if you need to modify anything, you don't have to `cleartool mktrtype -replace` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what language you're using, returning a non-zero return code (i.e. `1`) should do the trick. I've written this line of Perl many, many times to make a ClearCase trigger not allow an operation to proceed.

```
exit 1;
```

Worked every time.

Comment: I am using Perl, tried to return 1 but nothing happened, maybe I am misleading something. The code is this: 

if ( $CLEARCASE_COMMENT eq "" )
        {


        $text = "No comments entered, checkin operation will abort...";

 

        system("clearprompt proceed -mask proceed -type error -prompt \"$text\"");
 
 exit 1;

        }

Comment: I just checked one of my old triggers that interrupted checkin based on file size and it used `exit 1;`. I know that trigger worked. What does your `mktrtype` command look like? (You could update your question with that edit.)

Comment: install command looks like this: 
`mktrtype -element -all -preop checkin -exec <trigger_path> COMMENT_CONTROL`
I agree it seems obvious to expect to work, but it doesn't, it gives the error message and checkin happens.

Comment: after I've changed the triggers extension from .bat file to .pl and re-installed accordingly, it worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: What happens if you try this instead (replacing `exit 1;` with `die ($text);`? `if ( $CLEARCASE_COMMENT eq "" ) { $text = "No comments entered, checkin operation will abort..."; system("clearprompt proceed -mask proceed -type error -prompt \"$text\""); die ($text); }`...of course, I now see your post that you got it working. Great to hear!

Answer (score 1):

First, don't try to cram everything in the `mktrtype` command: your trigger definition should call a script (accessible by all users), in which you can program all the checks you want.

You can see in this [preop checkin trigger](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/4311.html#N104A8) an example of a script which must display a message an stop if certain conditions aren't met.

It is based on an error function:

```
########################################################################
# SUBROUTINE ERROR
#
sub error {
    close(WORKFILE);
    unlink($workFile);
    my ($message) = @_;
    die ($message."\nUnable to continue checkin ...\n");
}
```

At any point in the script, you would call:

```
&error("$message");
```

That would stop the checkin to proceed while displaying the error message to the user.

It is part of a script that you would declare as a trigger with the command:

```
cleartool mktrtype -c "RCS Keyword substitution in a source file" -element -all -preop checkin -eltype text_file -execwin "ccperl \\mw-ddiebolt\triggers\keyword_subst.perl" -execunix "Perl /net/titeuf/triggers/keyword_subst.perl" KEYWORD_SUBST
```

---

If this is too sophisticated, [this other script](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/4311.html#N103B8) uses `exit` like so:

```
sub checkUserName {
  my $user = shift(@_);

  my $currentUser = uc($ENV{CLEARCASE_USER});

 if ($user !~ m/^($currentUser)/) {
    `clearprompt proceed -mask proceed -type error -prompt \"Can't create label f
    exit 1;
  }
  exit 0;
}
```

That should be the same than your:

```
system("clearprompt proceed -mask proceed -type error -prompt \"$text\""); 
exit 1;
```